# Not Drawing Image After Clearing Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to clear my canvas the redraw it -30 pixel on the x axis. When I run it the canvas clears but doesn't redraw the canvas. When i run it without the "clearRect" it works put just draws the images over the current ones. Does anybody know what the problem? Thanks in advance

```
ctx.save();
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 480, 400);
ctx.translate(-30, 0);
ctx.drawImage(mycanvasvariable, 0, 0);
ctx.restore();
```

Answer (score 1):

A Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/555EH/

**Problem:** You are translating to the same x-coordinate each time (-30).

Try this which uses a variable (offsetX) to change the x-coordinate:

```
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

var offsetX=250;
var offsetY=100;

var mycanvasvariable=new Image();
mycanvasvariable.onload=start;
mycanvasvariable.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/house32x32transparent.png";
function start(){
   draw(offsetX,offsetY);
}

function draw(offsetx,offsety){
    ctx.save();
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 480, 400);
    ctx.translate(offsetx, offsety);
    ctx.drawImage(mycanvasvariable, 0, 0);
    ctx.restore();    
}

document.addEventListener("keydown",handleKeydown,false);
function handleKeydown(e){
    switch(e.keyCode){
        case 39: offsetX+=10; break;  // right arrow
        case 37: offsetX-=10; break;  // left arrow
        case 40: offsetY+=10; break;  // up arrow
        case 38: offsetY-=10; break;  // down arrow
    } 
    draw(offsetX,offsetY);
}
```

Comment: the function I run is on a key press so how could I implement that function into the key press one, do you know>

Comment: Sure…(1) Listen for keyboard events: document.addEventListener("keydown",handleKeydown,false); (2) handle the keyboard events and respond to the appropriate keyCodes:  function handleKeydown(e){ var key=e.keyCode; if(key==39){// move right}else if(key==37){// move left};}

Comment: I know how to test for key presses, thanks, I cant figure out how do incorporate your function and mine

Comment: You're welcome!  You can decrease offsetX in response to a left key and increase offsetX in response to a right key.

Comment: I have figured out that "mycanvasvariable" which is the canvas itself is not saving so when i redraw it, it shows blank because it did not save. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: I updated my answer with a demo of how to use the arrowkeys to move the image.